# alguien sabe como definir el favicon de html2pdf?

Tags: html, pdf

al crear el pdf (html2pdf) con dicha librería si el pdf se muestra en el navegador, asigna un favicon por default, alguien sabe como cambiarlo o asignarle alguno especifico?

```
$content = '<H3>HOLA MUNDO</h3>' 
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php');
try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr'); 
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $html2pdf->Output('exemple00.pdf');
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Creeria que no, por lo general ese lo establece el navegador ya que no lo muestras embebido, sino que muestras el pdf directamente, ahora bien si lo embebes en el html podrias setearlo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Agrega un poco mas de información sobre como lo estás haciendo, por favor. Un __[mcve]__ sería lo ideal.

Comment: agrege un pequelo hola mundo :)